# Google Maps API Javascript - toggling two different markers for one marker group

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with two groups of markers; let's call them groupA (red markers) and groupB (purple markers). I have a checkbox on my page to toggle on/off these two groups of markers. I want to add a third marker to the mix (grey markers) that will be shown *with* groupA. I've tried making some changes that I thought were obvious, but no luck for this novice. The grey markers just stay on the map and don't toggle on/off with the GroupA markers. I'm sure this is an easy fix. Thank you for any help!

Here is my javascript with my attempted changes:

```
    <script>        
        var markerGroups = {
    "GroupA": [],
    "GroupB": []
    "GroupC": []
};
var customIcons = {
// Maps Icons Collection https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com
    GroupA: {
        icon: '/icon_red.png'
    },
    GroupB: {
        icon: '/icon_purple.png'
    },
    GroupC: {
        icon: '/icon_grey.png'
    }
};
var map;
function load() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.357250, -75.272855),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain',
        gestureHandling: 'greedy',

        mapTypeControl: true,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
          },
          zoomControl: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
          },
          fullscreenControl: true,
          fullscreenControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
          },
          scaleControl: true,
          streetViewControl: false,
          streetViewControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
          },
          fullscreenControl: true



    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    // downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = parseXml(xmlStr); // data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        bounds.extend(point);
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
        });
        markerGroups[type].push(marker);
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
    // });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

function toggleGroup(type) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
        // alert(markerGroups[type][i]);
        var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
        if (!marker.getVisible()) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);

function parseXml(str) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
    } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
    }
}

var xmlStr = '<markers><marker name="This is a red marker" address="" lat="" lng="" type="GroupA"/><marker name="This is a purple maker" address="" lat="" lng="" type="GroupB"/><marker name="This is a grey marker " address="" lat="" lng="" type="GroupC"/></markers>';
```

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="GroupA" onclick="toggleGroup('GroupA', 'GroupC')" CHECKED/>GroupA

<input type="checkbox" id="GroupB" onclick="toggleGroup('GroupB')" CHECKED/>GroupB

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array

HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="GroupA" onclick="toggleGroup(['GroupA', 'GroupC'])" CHECKED/>GroupA

<input type="checkbox" id="GroupB" onclick="toggleGroup(['GroupB'])" CHECKED/>GroupB

<div id="map"></div>
```

JS

```
 function toggleGroup(type) {
    type.forEach(element => {
        for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[element].length; i++) {
            alert(markerGroups[element][i]);
            var marker = markerGroups[element][i];
            if (!marker.getVisible()) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **always** want GroupC to toggle with GroupA, just call both `toggleGroup('GroupA')` and `toggleGroup('GroupC')` when the checkbox is clicked:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="GroupA" onclick="toggleGroup('GroupA');toggleGroup('GroupC')" CHECKED/>GroupA
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qknaoycg/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markerGroups = {
  "GroupA": [],
  "GroupB": [],
  "GroupC": []
};
var customIcons = {
  // Maps Icons Collection https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com
  GroupA: {
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png'
  },
  GroupB: {
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/purple.png'
  },
  GroupC: {
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/grey.png'
  }
};
var map;

function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.357250, -75.272855),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',

    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    fullscreenControl: true,
    fullscreenControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    fullscreenControl: true
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  // downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
  var xml = parseXml(xmlStr); // data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    bounds.extend(point);
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon
    });
    markerGroups[type].push(marker);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }
  // });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

function toggleGroup(type) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
    // alert(markerGroups[type][i]);
    var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
    if (!marker.getVisible()) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}

var xmlStr = '<markers><marker name="This is a red marker" address="" lat="40" lng="-117" type="GroupA"/><marker name="This is a purple maker" address="" lat="41" lng="-117.5" type="GroupB"/><marker name="This is a grey marker " address="" lat="40" lng="-117.8" type="GroupC"/></markers>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="GroupA" onclick="toggleGroup('GroupA');toggleGroup('GroupC')" CHECKED/>GroupA

<input type="checkbox" id="GroupB" onclick="toggleGroup('GroupB')" CHECKED/>GroupB

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!